# Git checkout a new branch from a specific commit

Tags: git

I checkout a new branch B from a commit (say, 1234567) in branch A:

```
git checkout -b B 1234567
```

I committed that history commit in Sep.1st.

After hours of work in this new branch, I find a file whose modified date is today(Oct.17th). Say, I expect that file to be file0, but I now have file1.
So I think I have modified this file by mistake. I replace it with file0 copied from my colleague's computer and commit. Then, I checkout to another branch, delete branch B with `git branch -D B` and checkout the branch again, and then it's still file1.

I use `git log`, the latest commit was on Sep. 1st.

What puzzles me still, is that first time I checkout the new branch, the file modified time is, say 3:00pm, but it changes to 5:00pm the second time.

Comment: Git does not care the modified date of a file. You can repeatedly touch an existing file without modifying its contents and run `git status`. You'll find it unchanged. But Git does record the date when you make the commit.